# phonegap-base64 plugin - how to use at the ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I added the plugin by using the link at cli.

Plugin: phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.device

Plugin-Link: https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64

Now I did copy the code in my controller, but it does not work.

Code:

`//filePath is the absolute path to the file(/mnt/sdcard/...)
window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile(filePath, function(base64){
            console.log('file base64 encoding: ' + base64);
        });`

My question is, how do I activate the plugin? Like using for example "$cordovaCamera". Maybe somebody can show me a correct controller example. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Christoph, The base64 converting is very simple with this plugin , we just need to call this function and pass the file path to that function and it will retun the full base64 string :
here is a simple example :

```
       // Loop through acquired images
       window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile(filePath, function(base64){
           alert("Base64 image : "+base64);
           var base64Data = base64;
       //Use this base64 where you wants
         });
```

I hope it will help ypu to convert file to base64 .
have a happy code day